# Dagger-reflect: class defines multiple @Inject-annotations constructors

Tags: android, dagger-2

I try to use [dagger-reflect](https://github.com/JakeWharton/dagger-reflect) in my app to improve build speed for debug version of the app.

Unfortunately my app crashes in the runtime and displays stack trace with following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.example.MyClass defines multiple 
@Inject-annotations constructors
```

MyClass written in kotlin looks like this:

```
class MyClass @Inject constructor(@HostQualifier host: String = "")
```

and I use dagger module like this to provide host:

```
@Module
object SampleModule {
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    @HostQualifier
    fun provideHost(): String = "Example"
}
```

Comment: I think you dont need to provide MyClass if you already inject its constructor

Comment: Yes. I don't provide MyClass in the module. I just inject it in Activity

Comment: may be you are missing a @Component(modules = [SampleModule::class]) class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with using kotlin's default values in injected constructor.

Code like this:

```
class MyClass @Inject constructor(@HostQualifier host: String = "")
```

generates second constructor with `@Inject` annotation. 
That is why it causes exception:

```
MyClass defines multiple @Inject-annotations constructors
```

Solution is just removing default value from constructor:

```
class MyClass @Inject constructor(@HostQualifier host: String)
```